# string.Replace not working with triple forward slash (///) - proper way?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string path that starts with "file:///" and I am trying to remove it using string.Replace. Here is my code:

```
//This returns a string that starts with "file:///"
string missionPath = missionDataBase.FileLocationLocal; 

missionPath = missionPath.Replace("file///","");
```

Whenever I check missionPath after the replace, the file:/// is still there - how do you appropriately handle forward slashes when removing them from a string?

Comment: You are missing the *colon* between `file` and the triple slashes… It should be `missionPath.Replace("file:///", "");`

Comment: wow...such a noob mistake on my part - thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a colon in your search string.

```
missionPath = missionPath.Replace("file:///","");
```